# Why Java / Scala use extends / implements keywords?

Tags: java, c#, scala, inheritance

As compiler can easily differentiate between `class` and `interface` in Java, why provide explicit keywords `extends` and `implements` and add verbosity to the code? For example:

```
class Animal{}
interface FourLegged{}
class Dog : Animal, FourLegged {} // why can't we have this syntax in Java
```

I don't see any reason why Java can't provide C# like syntax in future releases without breaking existing code base. Is there any reason, please explain.

### Edit

Sorry about editing my question in between but my similar question is for Scala as well. As Patrick Hofman pointed out below:

> They surely can, but Java has always been a little more verbose in
>   their language than C#.

In case of Java, I agree with him. But I think Scala has preferred cleanliness over verbosity (eg. `;` is optional) and it can also differentiate among `class`, `interface` and `trait`. Why it also followed Java's path in this regard?

Comment: i guess thats why java has a characteristic `simple` focuses more on clarity of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They surely can, but Java has always been a little more verbose in their language than C#.

From the Java code you can read it *extends* or *implements*, in C# you have to rely on naming conversions to see if it *extends* or *implements*. I like the expressiveness of Java although I am a C# developer from the early beginnings of .NET.

Comment: Agree, but why is it implemented the same way in Scala? Please see my updated question.

Comment: The answer is the same: the language design team has made a decision. *They* found this the best way at the time. Also consider some background, for C# that has been mostly C++ and Java.

Comment: I think you mean more verbose/less expressive.

Comment: Perhaps they wanted to target Java audience which are very well familiar with `extends` and `implements`.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to point out about the readability of the code by  using `extends` and `implements`.

As you mentioned the *C#* code

```
class Dog : Animal, FourLegged {}
```

Here the compiler will know by itself but a developer may need to check what type of `Animal/FourLegged` types are.

With the java code

```
class Dog extends Animal implements FourLegged {}
```

it is just clear that `Animal` is a class (may be `abstract` class as well) where there might be default implementations are there. And `FourLegged` is an interface which is being used for implementing polymorphism.

Comment: Actually, both `extending` Classes and `implementing` Interfaces are forms of polymorphism. Having those two distinct keywords exist only makes the refactoring process more difficult. I believe the only purpose these constructs serve is justifying the laziness of compiler writers

Answer (score 0):

Actually Scala didn't follow Java. Scala only has `extends`, and has the `with` keyword for composing types to extend from.

```
scala> trait Foo
defined trait Foo

scala> trait Bar
defined trait Bar

scala> class Baz extends Foo with Bar
defined class Baz
```

Comment: That's right but my point was that Scala compiler can easily differentiate between `class` and `trait`, isn't it?

Comment: It can, and whether you extend from a class or trait doesn't matter: you always use `extends`.