# Why Callback Interface of Java extended and not implemented in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I was writing a kafka producer API with asynchronous method. So, I used a Callback interface to print metadata.

The java code is:

```
private static class ProducerCallback(ProducerRecord<String, String> record) implements Callback {.....}
```

Scala code:

```
private class ProducerCallback(record: ProducerRecord[String, String]) extends Callback{...}
```

Why in scala the Callback is extended and not implemented?

Comment: Because Scala's designers didn't consider the distinction between `extends` and `implements` to be useful enough. (C# and Kotlin don't make it either)

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I agree it is not useful ... But if "scala designers" thought, that, then why do they have `with` and `extends`? :D
I think the real reason here is just how syntax in scala works: the first thing has to be `extends`, it can't be `with`, so there is no any choice here.

Comment: @Dima Scala has `with` and `extends` because it has classes and traits (and because it does not support multiple inheritance).

Comment: @Dima It's kind of a pun: `D extends A with B with C` can be read as `D extends (A with B with C)` (though it isn't actually parsed this way), and `D` _is_ a subtype of `A with B with C`.

Comment: @Tim Yeah, I know, it _pretends_ that that is the difference (you "extend" classes "with" traits"), but it's a lie. For instance here `Callable` is an interface (trait), but you still "extend" it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why in Scala the `Callback` is extended and not implemented?

Different languages.  Clearly, the Java and Scala language designers made different choices on this point.

Why?

I have not managed to find<sup>1</sup> a clear explanation from the Scala designers as to why they chose to not copy Java's `extends` + `implements` distinction.  However, as general observation that they tend to favor a clean / concise syntax over a more verbose one.

It is clear that Scala "works" without making the distinction, and if the language doesn't need to make the distinction, the clean / concise approach is not to do that.

See also: [Why Java / Scala use extends / implements keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36762319/why-java-scala-use-extends-implements-keywords)

(Why does Java make the distinction?  It doesn't really matter: it is ancient history.)

---

<sup>1 - Either none is extant, or my google skills failed me.  If anyone finds one, please comment ...</sup>